# После нажатия на input radio li должен скрыться?

Tags: jquery

Всем привет, делаю to-do задачу, есть список задача с input radio, после нажатия он должен удалиться, то есть пропасть списка (само удаления задачи проходит успешно), не могу выполнить jquery часть.

Пример:
Удаляю какую-нибудь задачу, весь li скрывается??? Не могу понять как скрыть определенный li.

```
<li class="list-group-item task" id="<?= $res['id'] ?>">
    <input type="radio" name="radioTask" class="radioTask" value="<?= $res['id'] ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="list-task"><?= $res['task'] ?></span>
    </label>
</li>

    // это часть отправляет value значение в PHP
    $(".radioTask").change(function () {
    var val = $(".radioTask:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "",
        data: {val: val},

    });
    // а вот это часть должна скрывать .task блок
    $('li').each(function (index, value) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.radioTask').hide(this.id === val)
});
```

Comment: `$(this).remove()` вместо `$("li").each(...)`

Comment: так же там `$(this).val()` вместо `checked`

Comment: код приведите в вопросе, здесь также можно добавить сниппет. без кода тут вопрос совершенно не ясен, а ссылки на сторонние источники не приветствуются

Comment: @teran спасибо огромное выручили, я сделал для себя вот так и все работает
`$('.task').click(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });`

Comment: @teran как мне поставить Вам благодарность?!

Comment: можете заапвоутить коммент. но лучше напишите ответ на свой вопрос, содержащий корректный код. вопросы без ответа это плохо.

Answer (score 0):

Как @teran написал в комментах что можно `$(this).remove()`, а мне подошло `fadeOut()`

```
// Remove task
$(".radioTask").click(function () {
    var val = $(".radioTask:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "",
        data: {val: val},
    });
    // FadeOut task
    $('.task').click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(500)
        //$(this).remove();
    });
});
```